# Train named entity recognizer - problem with span object

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I'm creating a named entity recognizer. All's well, I'm able to put it in .spacy format. But when I train, I have a problem because some of my entities have spaces, tabs, etc.. The problem is that I can't clean up this text and then apply the function span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract") because that will shift everything. So I'd have to modify the span object... How do I do that?
Thanks a lot!

```
import json
import re
from spacy.util import filter_spans
from spacy.tokens import DocBin, Span

# Charger le modèle de langue français de spaCy
nlp = spacy.blank("fr")
doc_bin = DocBin()

# Texte donné
with open('Annotations/all.json','r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data = json.loads(line)
        text = data['text']
        labels = data['label']
        #print(data['id'],labels)
        doc = nlp.make_doc(text) 
        ents = []
        #print(text)
        #print(doc)
        for start, end, label in labels:
            span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
            if span is not None:
                ents.append(span)
            else:
                pass
        filtered_ents = filter_spans(ents)
        doc.ents = filtered_ents
        doc_bin.add(doc)
doc_bin.to_disk("training_data.spacy")
```

My json file (a sample):

```
"id":2800,"text":"Dossier n° 92.M.2016\/ca (180.M.2013)Parquet n° FAM-1161\/08Répertoire n° 16\/316ORDONNANCE                                            \t\t\t\t\t\t\tVu le jugement prononcé le 2 mai 2016 par le tribunal de la jeunesse de ce siège ;\tVu le réquisitoire déposé au greffe le 17 mai 2016 par Mme le Procureur du Roi et les procès-verbaux joints à ce réquisitoire ;Revu l’ordonnance rendue le 14 juin 2016 par le juge de la jeunesse de ce siège en cause de :\tPARENTE Tony, né le 08\/04\/1999, domicilié à 6830 BOUILLON, Allée de la Paroisse, 40, comparaît, assisté de son conseil, Maître Ch. GRESSE loco Maître David MOINET, avocat à 6600 BASTOGNE, rue Pierre Thomas, 4,et la mesure visée  aux articles 36-4º, 37 § 2, 2°,4°, 7°,  37 § 2 bis 2°,7°,9°,10°, 37 §2  quinquies, 37 § 2 bis 7°,  50 à 52 ter, 54 bis, 58 et 60, 62 de la loi du 8 avril 1965 relative à la protection de la Jeunesse mod. par la loi du 2 février 1994 et modifiée par la loi du 15 mai 2006 et du 13 juin 2006 et par le Décret du 4 mars 1991 et  1, 11 à 14, 31 à 37, 41 de la loi du 15 juin 1935;Vu le rapport d’observation\/orientation l’I.P.P.J. (SEVOR) de Saint-Hubert déposé au greffe le 7 juillet 2016 par Maître GRESSE ;Le Juge de la Jeunesse peut en tout temps modifier ou rapporter les mesures prises et agir au mieux des intérêts du mineur dans les limites de la loi du 8 avril 1965 sur la protection de la jeunesse ;Vu les renseignements recueillis et notamment l’audition de Tony PARENTE, assisté de son conseil Maître Ch. GRESSE loco Maître D. MOINET, et de son père Rudi PARENTE ;Ouï Maître Ch. GRESSE loco Maître D. MOINET, en sa plaidoirie pour le mineur ;Outre les faits repris dans le jugement prononcé le 2 mai 2016 par le tribunal de la jeunesse de ce siège, Tony PARENTE est soupçonné d’avoir à Bouillon :La nuit du 19 au 20 février 2016, en qualité d’auteur ou de coauteur volontairement fait des blessures ou porté des coups à Eric DELESTREE, avec la circonstance que les coups ou les blessures ont causé une maladie ou une incapacité de travail personnel (art. 392, 398 et 399 du Code pénal)Le 1er mai 2016, commis une attaque ou avoir résisté avec violences ou menaces envers en officier ministériel, un garde champêtre ou forestier, un dépositaire ou agent de la force publique, un préposé à la perception des taxes et des contributions, un porteur de contraintes, un préposé des douanes, un séquestre, un officier ou agent de la police administrative ou judiciaire, en l’occurrence envers Maxime COLLARD, Inspecteur, et Jean-Pascal WAVREILLE, Inspecteur, agissant pour l’exécution des lois, des ordres ou ordonnances de l’autorité publique, des mandats de justice ou jugements (art. 269, 271 et 483 du Code pénal)Les circonstances dans lesquelles les faits ont été commis ont été rappelées dans le jugement du 2 mai 2016 et dans l’ordonnance du 10 juin 2016 ;Il ressort du rapport de l’équipe éducative de l’I.P.P.J. que de l’avis de tous les intervenants la situation de Tony est inquiétante ;Depuis plusieurs années, les multiples intervenants qui l’ont suivi dressent un bilan interpellant de la situation tant socio-familiale que du parcours délinquant de Tony ; les nombreuses mesures d’aide mises en place n’ont jamais eu les effets attendus sur le comportement du jeune ; Tony semble s’enliser dans un mode de vie exempt de projets socio-professionnels et personnels durables ;L’équipe éducative conclut qu’un travail massif reste à réaliser avec ce jeune en lien avec la violence, qu’elle soit physique ou verbale, la consommation d’alcool et de produits stupéfiants, la responsabilisation de ses choix et les conséquences de ceux-ci tant pour autrui que pour lui-même ;Sa famille ne souhaite pas l’accueillir vu le comportement adopté par Tony et les pressions exercées sur son entourage pour obtenir ce qu’il souhaite, notamment de l’argent pour financer ses sorties bibitives ; vu la position de la famille, vu le risque important de récidive et les risques que Tony représente tant pour la société que pour lui-même, ce travail ne peut être effectué dans le cadre de la cellule familiale ; un retour en famille est dès lors prématuré ;Vu le risque de fugue de Tony, ce travail doit se faire au sein d’une structure fermée de type I.P.P.J. et ce sur du long terme ; ce type de mesure n’aura toutefois l’impact nécessaire que si Tony perçoit le sens de la mesure de placement, que s’il prend conscience de ses fragilités (violence, alcool) et s’il décide de changer radicalement de comportement ;Le projet exprimé par Tony lors de la réunion de synthèse du 5 juillet 2016, à savoir rentrer en famille tout en s’investissant dans une scolarité et dans un travail, est irréaliste et témoigne de l’absence de prise de conscience de Tony de sa situation et de la nécessité de prendre sa vie en main ;Vu la gravité des faits reprochés au mineur, des mesures contraignantes s’imposent afin de mettre un terme à l’escalade dans la délinquance et l’aider à construire un projet d’avenir ;Tony PARENTE est âgé de plus de 14 ans ; il a commis des faits qualifiés infraction qui s’ils avaient été commis par une personne majeure seraient de nature à entraîner au sens du Code pénal ou des lois particulières une peine de réclusion de 5 à 10 ans ou une peine plus lourde ;Il n’a pas présenté de projet écrit conformément à l’article 36 § 2ter de la loi du 8 avril 1965 ; vu la gravité des faits, une offre restauratrice ne peut être envisagée ;Vu les nouveaux faits reprochés à Tony PARENTE et le non-respect des conditions fixées par le jugement prononcé le 2 mai 2016, son placement à l’Institution Communautaire Publique de Protection de la Jeunesse de 6870 SAINT-HUBERT, au service évaluation et orientation en régime fermé, sera prolongé pour une durée de 30 jours à partir du 14 juillet 2016, sous la surveillance du Service de Protection Judiciaire de Neufchâteau ; les frais de ce placement seront pris en charge par la Fédération Wallonie-Bruxelles ; le tiers restant des allocations familiales sera attribué à Mme Linda MACOR ;Ce placement sera mis à profit pour aider Tony PARENTE à réfléchir aux faits qui lui sont reprochés et à l’impact de ceux-ci sur les victimes, à son comportement en général, à ses relations avec sa famille, à la nécessité de respecter l’autorité et à préparer un projet ; des démarches devront être réalisées en vue de rechercher le cas échéant un lieu de vie en-dehors de son milieu familial à sa sortie de l’institution ;Ces mesures seront fixées au maximum jusqu’au jour où le mineur aura atteint l’âge de 18 ans, sans préjudice de l’application de l’article 52 al. 9 de la loi du 8 avril 1965 ;Tant pour la sécurité du mineur que pour la sécurité publique, les mesures qui précèdent sont indispensables afin qu’il prenne conscience du caractère inadéquat de son comportement, de l’obligation de respecter l’intégrité et la propriété d’autrui ainsi que l’autorité et de construire un projet de vie ;La finalité de la mesure provisoire ne peut être atteinte d’une autre manière ;La situation sera revue à l’audience de cabinet du Juge de la Jeunesse de Neufchâteau du vendredi 12 août 2016 à Neufchâteau à 10h00 pour faire le point ;\t\t\tPAR CES MOTIFS,\t\tVu les articles 36-4º, 37 § 2, 2°,8°, 37 §2 quater et quinquies,   50 à 52 ter, 54 bis, 58 et 60, 62 de la loi du 8 avril 1965 relative à la protection de la Jeunesse mod. par la loi du 2 février 1994 et modifiée par la loi du 15 mai 2006 et du 13 juin 2006 et par le Décret du 4 mars 1991 et  1, 11 à 14, 31 à 37, 41 de la loi du 15 juin 1935;             Nous M.-N. ROUARD, Juge de la Jeunesse, assisté de V. SIMON, Greffier, avons rendu l'ordonnance suivante, \tDisons que le placement de Tony PARENTE à l’Institution Communautaire Publique de Protection de la jeunesse de 6870 SAINT-HUBERT, Thiers Del Borne, 7, au service évaluation et orientation en régime fermé, est renouvelé pour une durée de 30 jours à partir du 14 juillet 2016, sous la surveillance du Service de Protection Judiciaire de Neufchâteau,Disons que les frais de ce placement seront pris en charge par la Fédération Wallonie-Bruxelles,Disons que le tiers restant des allocations familiales sera attribué à Mme Linda MACOR,Disons que Tony PARENTE comparaîtra devant le Juge de la Jeunesse de Neufchâteau le vendredi 12 août 2016 à 10h00, à la diligence du Parquet.Ordonnons l’exécution provisoire de Notre décision,Chargeons le Ministère Public de son exécution,Fait à Neufchâteau le 7 juillet 2016.\tLe Juge de la Jeunesse,\t\t\t\t  Le Greffier, \tM.-N. ROUARD\t\t\t\t\tV. SIMON","label":[[0,89,"JURIS"],[16,21,"TIME"],[142,208,"JURIS"],[163,177,"TIME"],[250,258,"PROF+LAW"],[258,273,"TIME"],[276,300,"PROF+LAW"],[277,280,"TITLE"],[354,416,"JURIS"],[374,389,"TIME"],[443,455,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[460,474,"TIME"],[487,527,"LOC"],[563,569,"TITLE"],[569,581,"NAT_PERSON"],[586,593,"TITLE"],[593,606,"NAT_PERSON"],[607,613,"PROF+LAW"],[616,652,"LOC"],[675,1047,"LEG"],[817,830,"TIME"],[890,904,"TIME"],[931,961,"TIME"],[981,993,"TIME"],[1035,1047,"TIME"],[1109,1123,"CIT"],[1133,1139,"JURIS"],[1133,1139,"PROF+LAW"],[1140,1157,"TIME"],[1161,1168,"TITLE"],[1169,1175,"NAT_PERSON"],[1176,1199,"PROF+LAW"],[1319,1375,"LEG"],[1329,1343,"TIME"],[1437,1450,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[1474,1481,"TITLE"],[1481,1491,"NAT_PERSON"],[1497,1504,"TITLE"],[1504,1513,"NAT_PERSON"],[1529,1542,"NAT_PERSON"],[1547,1554,"TITLE"],[1554,1565,"NAT_PERSON"],[1571,1577,"TITLE"],[1577,1587,"NAT_PERSON"],[1670,1684,"TIME"],[1728,1742,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[1766,1774,"CIT"],[1775,1808,"TIME"],[1900,1915,"NAT_PERSON"],[2030,2064,"LEG"],[2065,2081,"TIME"],[2466,2482,"NAT_PERSON"],[2482,2492,"PROF"],[2497,2520,"NAT_PERSON"],[2519,2530,"PROF"],[2655,2689,"LEG"],[2771,2834,"JURIS"],[2786,2797,"TIME"],[2823,2835,"TIME"],[2948,2953,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[2971,2994,"TIME"],[3137,3142,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[3256,3260,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[3724,3730,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[3950,3955,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[4148,4155,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[4316,4321,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[4505,4509,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[4543,4558,"TIME"],[4716,4721,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[4967,4979,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[4983,5006,"TIME"],[5147,5183,"LEG"],[5184,5245,"TIME"],[5298,5346,"LEG"],[5331,5343,"TIME"],[5453,5465,"NAT_PERSON+PLAINTIFF"],[5510,5545,"LEG"],[5530,5544,"TIME"],[5563,5650,"LOC"],[5723,5772,"TIME"],[5797,5845,"LEG_ENTITY"],[5834,5846,"CIT"],[5903,5933,"LEG_ENTITY"],[5995,5999,"TITLE"],[5995,6011,"NAT_PERSON"],[6054,6066,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[6472,6528,"TIME"],[6563,6608,"LEG"],[6596,6608,"TIME"],[7044,7063,"PROF+LAW"],[7066,7079,"CIT"],[7082,7126,"TIME"],[7173,7512,"LEG"],[7281,7293,"TIME"],[7353,7368,"TIME"],[7394,7404,"TIME"],[7412,7424,"TIME"],[7445,7456,"TIME"],[7498,7510,"TIME"],[7529,7541,"NAT_PERSON"],[7543,7562,"PROF+LAW"],[7575,7583,"NAT_PERSON"],[7585,7593,"PROF+LAW"],[7659,7670,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[7674,7738,"LEG_ENTITY"],[7674,7781,"LOC"],[7855,7904,"TIME"],[7930,7962,"LEG_ENTITY"],[7966,7978,"CIT"],[8041,8073,"LEG_ENTITY"],[8145,8148,"TITLE"],[8145,8160,"NAT_PERSON"],[8172,8184,"NAT_PERSON+DEFENDANT"],[8204,8226,"PROF+LAW"],[8230,8242,"CIT"],[8242,8276,"TIME"],[8407,8418,"CIT"],[8418,8438,"TIME"],[8437,8462,"PROF+LAW"],[8466,8479,"PROF+LAW"],[8480,8506,"NAT_PERSON"]]}
```

Comment: Please post some sample data that can be used to run your code. This will help greatly.

Comment: Yes, sorry! It's done :)